# Yii2: Gii's model autocomplete doesn't work with non public schema

Tags: autocomplete, model, yii2, database-schema, gii

The **Table Name** field has the autocomplete feature. But it works only for the public schema, not for any other schema.

I have to type every letter of "my_schema.persons" because the autocomplete doesn't search for non public schemas. Then the model generator create successfully the model file.

[image: Creating a Gii's model.]

How can I enable autocomplete feature for non public schemas?

Comment: Is there a question here? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement you own generators inherited from standard ones. Look at [Gii readme](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-gii/blob/master/docs/guide/README.md).